# generating pi in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pi

I would like to know how to adapt this code to give me X digits of pi when asked
because right now it just prints a random amount

```
while True:
    print("how many digits of pi would you like")


    def make_pi():
        q, r, t, k, m, x = 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3
        number = int(input())
        for j in range(int(number)):
            if 4 * q + r - t < m * t:
                yield m
                q, r, t, k, m, x = 10 * q, 10 * (r - m * t), t, k, (10 * (3 * q + r)) // t - 10 * m, x
            else:
                q, r, t, k, m, x = q * k, (2 * q + r) * x, t * x, k + 1, (q * (7 * k + 2) + r * x) // (t * x), x + 2


    digits = make_pi()
    pi_list = []
    my_array = []

    for i in make_pi():
        my_array.append(str(i))

    my_array = my_array[:1] + ['.'] + my_array[1:]
    big_string = "".join(my_array)
    print("here is the string:\n %s" % big_string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print('{:.xf}'.format(math.pi))
```

Where `x` is the number of digits of pi you want to print after the decimal.

EDIT:

IF you want to do it you way then

```
big_string = ''.join(my_array[:x])
```

Where x is the number of *characters* including leading 3 and decimal point.

Comment: @Thomas: If you think this is a nice answer, you should up-vote it.

Comment: @Thomas The problem with that part of the answer is that it didn't initially answer the question...

Answer (score 0):

full code if interested

while True:
    print("how many digits of pi would you like")

```
def make_pi():
    q, r, t, k, m, x = 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3
    for j in range(1000):
        if 4 * q + r - t < m * t:
            yield m
            q, r, t, k, m, x = 10 * q, 10 * (r - m * t), t, k, (10 * (3 * q + r)) // t - 10 * m, x
        else:
            q, r, t, k, m, x = q * k, (2 * q + r) * x, t * x, k + 1, (q * (7 * k + 2) + r * x) // (t * x), x + 2


digits = make_pi()
pi_list = []
my_array = []

for i in make_pi():
    my_array.append(str(i))

number = int(input())+2
my_array = my_array[:1] + ['.'] + my_array[1:]
big_string = "".join(my_array[: number ])
print("here is the string:\n %s" % big_string)
```